# How do you use decimal as labels in sub-equations instead of only whole numbers in align?

Tags: numbering, align, subequations

In the `align` environment, it automatically labels consecutive lines within the same environment as (1),(2),...,(n), line by line. But I want it to organize equations more properly and use (1.0), (1.1), (1.2)... for the first equation in the first `align` environment, and then (2.0), (2.1), (2.2)... and etc for consecutive equations in following separate `align` environments. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: may be you need the `\subequations` environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you load the `etoolbox` package and use the `\patchcmd` macro to "patch" the `subequations` environment in two places.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'align' and 'subequations' environments
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\patchcmd' macro
\patchcmd{\subequations}{{0}}{{-1}}{}{}       % decrement the equation counter
\patchcmd{\subequations}{\alph}{.\arabic}{}{} % change display format of eq. counter

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
1+1=2\\
2+2=4\\
3+3=6
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
4+4=8\\
0+0=0\\
1-1=0
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I do what you say here, I get (~.a) (~.b) ... instead (~.1) (~.2) like you have here.  Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @yurnero - Did you copy the instruction `\patchcmd{\subequations}{\alph}{.\arabic}{}{}` into your document -- along with `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and `\patchcmd{\subequations}{{0}}{{-1}}{}{}`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I copied-and-pasted all three lines after `\usepackage(amsmath)` (as I already have that elsewhere in my preamble). I use `exarticle` document class. Does this matter?

Comment: @yurnero - No. By the way, my mind-reading skills are absolutely worthless. If you  describe a problem but don't provide actionable information about your document setup, the odds that I will somehow be able to diagnose what's going on and, better yet, come up with a solution are infinitesimally small. May I suggest that you post a *new query* to this site, ideally together with a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that reproduces the issue you would like to fix.

Comment: Hi sorry, I know the rule and didn't want to be cryptic or difficult. Was just gambling on the chance that you can detect quickly a reason for my phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use `mathtools` package to edit equation brackets. Use `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` to customize the way subequations tags will look like.

Equations and subequations start at 1 when numbered. To change this behavior, use `\AtBeginEnvironment` from `etoolbox`

```
\documentclass[]{book}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

    \usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage[]{mathtools}

        \newtagform{eqbrackets}[]{(}{)}
        \usetagform{eqbrackets}


    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \patchcmd{\subequations}{\alph{equation}}{.\arabic{equation}}{}{}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{alignat}{\addtocounter{equation}{-1}}


\begin{document}



\begin{subequations}


    \begin{alignat}{3}
        I_{sc} & = I_{sc,ref} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:SubEq1}
        \\
        %
        V_{oc} & = V_{oc,ref} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:SubEq2}
        \\
        %
        P_{mp} & = P_{mp,ref} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\gamma}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:SubEq3}
    \end{alignat}

\end{subequations}

See SubEq. \ref{eq:SubEq1}

\begin{subequations}

    \begin{alignat}{3}
        I_{sc} & = I_{sc,ref} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:SubEq4}
        \\
        %
        V_{oc} & = V_{oc,ref} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:SubEq5}
        \\
        %
        P_{mp} & = P_{mp,ref} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\gamma}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:SubEq6}
    \end{alignat}

\end{subequations}

See SubEq. \ref{eq:SubEq5}

\begin{subequations}

    \begin{alignat}{3}
        I_{sc} & = I_{sc,ref} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \\
        %
        V_{oc} & = V_{oc,ref} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \\
        %
        P_{mp} & = P_{mp,ref} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\gamma}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
    \end{alignat}

\end{subequations}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution would appear to work at present only for `alignat` environments. How would you generalize the solution to deal with `align` environments as well (which are employed by the OP) or, for that matter, for *any* numbered multi-line math environment?

Comment: I was just trying to offer the best help I can. In your solution you identified `{1}` refers to the subequation number when starting subequations and replaced it with `{0}` which leads to setting subequations number to 0 in `align` or `alignedat`. But how did you know that `{1}` in `\subequations` exist only once and refers to subeqiations numbering and decided that it is safe to replace it?

Comment: In the code for the `subequations` environment in the file `amsmath.sty`, there is the following instruction: `\setcounter{equation}{0}`. It's the *only* instance of `{0}`; that's why it's "safe" to replace it with `{-1}`.